# Attribute Routing ASP Core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, attributerouting

How do I specify routes to the following API endpoint using attribute routing?

The product object returned has a few attributes along with a Store and Manufacturer field that contain either null or a Store and Manufacturer object respectively.

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ProductsController : ControllerBase {


        [HttpGet ("")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>> Get(
            bool stores = false, int storeId = 0,
            bool manufacturers = false, int manufacturerId = 0
        ) {

            // Default - returns all Products 
            // stores = true will set Product.Store = to the store object
            // storeId = 1 will filter Products to those in Store 1
            // manufacturer = true will st Product.Manufacturer to a manufacturer object
            // manufacturerId = 1 will filter Product to those produced by manufacturer 1

            var products = await _ctx.GetProducts(
                stores, storeId, 
                manufacturers, manufacturerId
            );
            return products.ToList();
        }
```

I would like to have a few readable routes to access and set the parameters appropriately.

- `[HttpGet ("")]`

  - `/api/Products` to return objects with Store and Manufacturer = null. This is desirable.
  - The `("")` isn't needed when it is alone but necessary if I add other routes.
- `[Route("{stores=false}/{storeId=0})]`

  - `/api/Products/true` returns Product objects with Store filled and Manufacturer = null. This is good.
  - `/api/Products/true/1` filters on Store 1 which is also good.
  - But it is a stupid url (true? - products, stores, or manufacturers?)
- `[Route("Stores/{storeId?})]`

  - `/api/Products/Stores/1` leaves stores = false, though filters on Store 1 but does not include the stores object.  "Stores" is not in the route data.  It is in the Request.Path but I don't want to go there.
  - `/api/Products/Stores?storeId=1` doesn't work.  Request.QueryString.Value = ?storeId=1 but that doeesn't bind to my storeId argument.

I could continue describing my other experiments but suffice it to say, none gave me the results I'm looking for. I think I'm misunderstanding attribute routing but maybe it wasn't designed to do what I'm trying to do.

I guess what I'd like to see is either modifying a single url with a query string like,

- `/api/Products?stores=true&manufacturerId=1`to get products with store info that are produced by manufacturer 1, or
- `/api/Products?storeId=1,stores=true,manufacturers=true` to get full details about the products in store 1

Alternatively, it would be ok to have

- `/api/Products/Stores/1` to get Products with store info for products in store 1
- `/api/Products/Stores/Manufacturers/1` to get Projects with store and manufacturer info for those produced by manufacturer 1

Actually, I'm open to any URL schema that is readable.

Thanks!

Comment: _“none gave me the results I'm looking for”_ – What *are* you looking for ?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I would redesign the your API Controller a little bit. Would be good if you give some meaningful names to your actions instead of `Get()`.

I also would create a service which will have the logic to provide the requested product and replace the `_ctx`

```
    // Default - returns all Products 
    [HttpGet ("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>> GetAllProducts()
    {
        var products = await _ctx.GetAllProducts();
        return products.ToList();
    }

    // stores = true will set Product.Store = to the store object
    // storeId = 1 will filter Products to those in Store 1
    [HttpGet ("Stores/{storeId?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>> GetProductsByStore(int? storeId)
    {
        if (storeId.HasValue)
        {
            // get products by store id
            products = await _ctx.GetProductsByStoreId(storeId);
        }
        else
        {
             products = await _ctx.GetProductsByCurrentStore(); // just a suggestion I 
         have no idea what you mean by saying "..set Product.Store = to the store object"
        }

        return products.ToList();
    }

    // manufacturer = true will st Product.Manufacturer to a manufacturer object
    // manufacturerId = 1 will filter Product to those produced by manufacturer 1
    [HttpGet ("Manufacturers/{manufacturerId?}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Product>>> GetProductsByManufacturer(int? manufacturerId)
    {
        if (manufacturerId.HasValue)
        {
            products = await _ctx.GetProductsByManufacturerId(manufacturerId);
        }
        else
        {
            products = await _ctx.GetProductsByManufacturer();
        }

        return products.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about breaking up the controller method but it is limiting.  I might, for example want to filter on storeId but still have the Manufacturer data returned as part of the object.  Does attribute routing mean that controller methods have to be simple?

Comment: @bob I see you are returning `Product` and if the `Manufacturer` is part of that object I don't see problem returing it when filtering by Store. I am not sure I undarstand what are you asking, the routing has noting to do with how you build your controller logic